# Editing every cell in an Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a list of phone numbers in an Excel sheet as well as in Outlook. The sheet only has one column. I need to remove '92' from the beginning of each phone number.

e.g. In a cell that contains `9203337800071`, I need it to be `03337800071`

Comment: If you only need to do this once: Control-A, control-c.  Start an editor.  Control-V,  search and replace. (e.g %s/^92/), copy and paste back.

Comment: If 92 is on every cell, you can use =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-2) and just put that next to every cell, and you get the values without the 92.

Answer (score 0):

Using Excel, assuming your data starts at A1:

Put this in B1, then copy it down the entire sheet. After that's done, copy column B and use "Paste Values" to overwrite column A. Then you can delete column B.

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,2)="92",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),A1)
```

The formula above is partly based on the one @Darius provided [in a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/820391/editing-every-cell-in-an-excel-sheet#comment1075408_820391), but this version has some logic built-in to account for the possibility that some numbers may *not* start with 92 and assumes that you want to leave such numbers as-is.

Walkthrough of the formula:

- `IF(LEFT(A1,2)="92",` - If the first two characters in A1 are 92...
- `RIGHT(A1,(LEN(A1)-2),` - ...make this cell's value equal to A1, without the first two characters...
- `A1)` - ...otherwise (A1 does *not* start with 92), make this cell's value equal to A1 exactly.